# "Compassion Was the Most Important, Perhaps the Sole Law of Human Existence."

Tags: punctuation, commas

> "Compassion was the most important, perhaps the sole law of human existence.”
>
> ― Fyodor Dostoyevsky, *The Idiot*

What may seem the grammatical function of this comma, here? I think, I thought, if a comma marks a phrase, there may seem two . . .

> Compassion was the most important ― perhaps the sole ― law of human existence.
>
> Compassion was the most important ― perhaps the sole law ― of human existence.
>
> Compassion was the most important, (perhaps the sole law), of human existence.
>
> Compassion was the most important, (perhaps the sole), law of human existence.
>
> Compassion was the most important (perhaps the sole law) of human 
>   existence.
>
> Compassion was the most important (perhaps the sole) law of human existence.
>
> Compassion was the most important, perhaps the sole, law of human existence.
>
> Compassion was the most important, perhaps the sole law, of human existence.

May any of these seem grammatically proper, and work?

Comment: Compassion was the most important ― perhaps the sole ― law of human existence.  Yes.  Punctuation is conventional.  Its "rules" are loose and vary over time. Do not seek to make sense of a sentence primarily from its punctuation. Let syntax be your guide.  You should seek to be able to understand that sentence even if it were unpunctuated.

Comment: Compassion was the most important, (perhaps the sole law), of human existence.  Compassion was the most important, perhaps the sole law, of human existence.No.  The "sentence" outside the parenthetic does not make sense. The most important *what*?

Comment: Interesting. I guess, I, maybe, thought *Compassion* seemed like, maybe, a subject, *was* seemed like a copular verb, and *the most important* maybe a noun phrase and maybe a subject complement, *Compassion was the most important*. I do thank you, TRomano. I guess, I may not get a grammatical function of that comma. I think, I thought two commas, maybe, encompass a phrase.

Comment: "the most important of human existence" is a malformed noun-phrase.

Comment: I may not get the meaning of malformed noun phrase, and, or, why it may seem like that. I guess, I thought *the most important* seemed like the noun phrase; so, the sentence, (clause[?]), may go *Compassion (subject[?]) was (copular verb[?]) the most important (noun phrase, subject complement[?])*. I guess, with the comma, it may not make sense. I guess, I, mostly, may not get the grammatical function of this comma, here, and why there may only seem one. I thank you, TRomano.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If I were going to repunctuate the sentence to help learners understand it, it would be as OP has it:

> Compassion was the most important ― perhaps the sole ― law of human
>   existence.

The phrase "perhaps the sole" is a parenthetic remark, a tentative revision of the previous "the most important".  It may be topmost in importance of the laws of human existence, or it may be the *only* law of human existence.

If we say

> He is the **oldest of** the cousins.

the plural noun **cousins** supplies the referent set that superlative *oldest* requires.

The preposition **of** introduces the set to which *he* belongs: he is a cousin.
Among that set of cousins, he is the oldest.

But if we say

> Compassion is the **most important of** human existence

the singular noun **existence** does not identify a referent set, and so we must ask, Compassion is the most important *what*?

We could say

> Of all human *virtues*, compassion is the most important.

or

> Compassion is the most important of human *virtues*.

We could even rely upon a noun in a previous sentence, which is implicitly "carried forward" as the referent:

> Today we are going to talk about virtues.   I think compassion is the
>   most important (one).

Comment: I think, I, may, see. I guess, I thought *of human existence* seemed like a, maybe, prepositional phrase. So, I maybe read it like *Of human existence, compassion is the most important*.

Comment: I am not disputing that "of human existence" is a prepositional phrase. I am saying that the abstract noun *existence* does not provide the necessary referent set the superlative "most important" requires. What would you make of this sentence? *Of human existence, it is the loudest.*  What is "it"?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand the usage of the comma in the original sentence when the sentence is on its own. If it **is** correctly placed, the meaning is probably different to that of your versions- perhaps something like this:

> Compassion was the most important. [It was] perhaps the sole law of human existence.”

You will probably find [this explanation](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/comma.html) of the use of commas useful: see the section on *interrupting elements*. The same site explains the differences in usage between commas, em-dash and parentheses. In my opinion, comma and em-dash work in these sentences but parentheses do not.

Generally speaking, if you separate out an interrupting element with commas, you should be able to remove the bit in commas without affecting the meaning of the remaining sentence.  This works when **law** is outside the commas:

> Compassion was the most important ... law of human existence.

It does not work if **law** is inside the commas

> Compassion was the most important ... of human existence.

Comment: So, may that, maybe, mean it may seem like a, maybe, parenthetical? I guess, I may not get why there may seem only one comma.

Answer (score 0):

I won't rule out a chance of the translator's quirk or error.

Originally, in a Russian phrase*, it is possible to put an optional comma in the sentence, but the author didn't do so. Maybe the translator wanted to keep the flavor of the original punctuation or something like that.

Also, it might be a  mistake. If JavaLatte's answer is correct, and one comma implies this meaning:

> Compassion was the most important. [It was] perhaps the sole law of
>   human existence.

Then the translation have accidentally changed the meaning of the original phrase; it was supposed to mean "compassion is the main, and perhaps the only, law of human existence".

*<sub>The original quote looks like "Сострадание есть главнейший, и, может быть, единственный {you might put a comma here, or might omit it} закон бытия всего человечества".</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Compassion was the most important, perhaps the sole law of human existence. 
It depends on the context and what was intended to be said by the author without being written. If he meant, for example, compassion is the most important **in these relationships like motherhood, friendship, neighborhood, ...etc**, his idea stops in **important** and not in the **law**. Therefore, **compassion** was the most **important**  and the hidden idea is **( the most important in human relationships)**. Thus, all the sentence **perhaps the sole law of human existence.** is **additional**. 
That means if the writer meant that compassion is the most important **law**, the comma should precede the word **law**, so the sentence between the commas **perhaps the sole** would become the additional one.